# What is the actions table for and can I delete orphaned actions?

Tags: 7, actions

I just ran

```
$ drush cc all -v
```

and it tells me I have orphaned actions. I'm curious to what the actions table is for in Drupal 7 and if it's safe to just drop all the data in the actions table?

Answer (score 3):

There is no button or link or even an indication that orphans exist when going to `/admin/config/system/actions`.

I don't really get why, but when I visit [`/admin/config/system/actions/orphan`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/7.67/modules/system/system.module#L977-983) the orphaned actions are removed.  I'm watching the Drupal log when I go to that path and it systematically removes all the orphans.

Answer (score 2):

If you visit `/admin/config/system/actions` you will see a list of the actions currently on your system. These actions are declared in the modules (named under *Action Type*), and may be orphaned if a module is de-activated.

Clearing orphaned actions is fine, but if you drop the table, you will break your site.

Comment: i have a bunch of actions, but i dont think they all are orphaned: http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/5817/2yed.jpg -- know of anyway to just delete the orphaned ones?

Comment: Go to `/admin/config/system/actions/orphan`. If you have orphaned actions, it will give you the opportunity to remove them.

Comment: i dont see an option for that and if i put in the path you give me with /orphan. it just redirects me back to /manage

Comment: Then you have no orphaned actions. Leave everything alone.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module then you can simply go to `your-site/devel/php` and then execute the below code:

```
actions_synchronize(TRUE);
```

Your question indicates you have `drush` so you could evaluate the command with that;

`drush eval 'actions_synchronize(TRUE)'`

If you need to do this on a remote install where you don't have access to `drush` you can add this to a custom module's `.install` file with a [hook_update_n()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7.x)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_update_n().
 * actions_synchronize().
 */
function yourmodule_update_7001() {
  actions_synchronize(TRUE);
}
```

and then execute `yoursite/update.php`. You can test this locally using `drush updb` as well.